# Insert after grabbing a mysqli_insert_id value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This has sorta been an on going problem for me, after I insert into a table in my db I grab the ID that was just generated using $user_id_number = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);

I need to take that value and insert it into the table I just inserted into but into a different column, this is my code

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {
    // The username is unique, so insert the data into the database
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO user_register (user_email, user_password, register_date_time) VALUES ('$user_email', SHA('$user_password1'), NOW())";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query1);

    //Grab the primary id key that was just created 
    $user_id_number = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);

    //store Id key in variable for new directory name 
    $directory_name = 'user_id_'.$user_id_number;

    //use id key to name directory
    mkdir($directory_name);

    //Add the new directory name in user_register table 
    $query2 = "UPDATE `user_register` SET `client_folder`= [$directory_name] WHERE user_id = $user_id_number";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
```

It does the first insert, created the directory but does not go on to update the directory name into the table?!!? I have also tried insert and get the same result...any ideas?

ps...I am trying to create a new directory that is named with info from the primary id then can be called later so I can put a new directory in that directory

Comment: Look: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The update query:

```
$query2 = "UPDATE `user_register` SET `client_folder`= '$directory_name' WHERE user_id = $user_id_number";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `$directory name` is a string you will need to surround with quotes

```
client_folder = '$directory_name' WHERE user_id = $user_id_number";
              //^here         //^and here
```

Answer (score 0):

$query2 = "UPDATE `user_register` SET `client_folder`= **[**$directory_name**]** WHERE user_id = $user_id_number";

Remove the "[" and "]"